# Pain on the 5th Metatarcel and Cuboid

Tags: pedals, clipless, pain

I have got a new set of clipless pedals and shoes. Hardly used it for some 15 rides.
Whenever I use it I feel a pain on my left foot's 5th Metatarcel and Cuboid bones.
There is no pain whatsoever on the right foot.
I am using [this pedals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WYAENC) and [this pair of shoes](http://www.vittoria-shoes.com/eng/products-dett.php?id_art=20&cat=MTB).

On the right set, The shoe is tightly set to the pedals after locking, that is, there is no lateral swivelling of my foot while riding.
But on the left side, my foot slightly swivels laterally. Could this be the reason?

Please let me know, if you had any similar pain and how you controlled it...

Comment: I had this problem about 5 years ago. In my case changing to wider shoes and getting custom orthotics solved the problem. I use half size Sidi Megas. Half size, because I've read they're slightly wider. I think I've also change my pedal dynamics slightly, putting less pressure on the ball of my foot.

Answer (score 1):

With these shoes you probably use Shimano's SPD-pedals or similar MTB pedals. Most, if not all of these do have some angular float of the heel when the clip is engaged. It is part of the system. I'd worry if there's no float.
As with the pain on your left foot it could be caused by the position of the foot on the pedal. Ideally the axle of the pedal would be under the ball of the big toe. You might experiment here by moving the cleat fore or aft. Go for a ride, take along an Allen key and experiment settings.

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be noted that I am not a doctor and none of this should be construed as medical advice - if you have pain, you should use your common sense to choose if/when to see a doctor.

It sounds like something is screwy with the float on the right pedal.

A lot of bike shops offer fitting sessions for bike shoes as well as the whole bike. In particular, they'll try different sets of shoes and cleats with some pedal so that you get different amounts of float and tension and rotation of the pedals (a picture to illustrate that is [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/shoe-pedal.html)) a comfortable riding position - you may want to do this. This may be a good investment if you can afford it.

Failing this, if you can't get it adjusted, you may need to go with a different shoe or pedal (or go toe clips/platform).